# appengine base64 encoded string is different from my local machine's

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding, base64, decoding

This is the code:

```
>>> import base64
>>> id = 1
>>> key = "secret key very long"
>>> enc = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(id)+key)
>>> enc
'MXNlY3JldCBrZXkgdmVyeSBsb25n'
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc)
'1secret key very long'
```

Works as intended on my machine, but when I upload this code to google appengine, both encoded and decoded strings are totally different. How come?

EDIT 1:
this is the actual code:

```
import base64
id = 18005
key = "r-$b*8hglm+858&9t043hlm6-&6-3d3vfc4((7yd0dbrakhvi"
enc = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(id)+key)
print enc
# local machine: MTgwMDVyLSRiKjhoZ2xtKzg1OCY5dDA0M2hsbTYtJjYtM2QzdmZjNCgoN3lkMGRicmFraHZp
# appengine: PXItJGIqOGhnbG0rODU4Jjl0MDQzaGxtNi0mNi0zZDN2ZmM0KCg3eWQwZGJyYWtodmkxODAwNQ==
```

Comment: Can you show the different results you get?  PS: if key is really a secret, base64 isn't doing much to protect it.

Comment: Curious. I get identical results here http://shell.appspot.com/

Comment: @Ned, I have updated the code. PS: How do I protect the key then?

Comment: @Adam, I know, the error doesn't occur in the admin console for some reason.

Comment: You might try printing values of `id` and `key` to ensure they contain what you expect.

Comment: To 'protect' the key? Don't send it to a user in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain *why* per se, but decoding the string you got from appengine shows it prepended an '=' to your key; and *appended*, rather than prepended, the ID.

```
>>> key='r-$b*8hglm+858&9t043hlm6-&6-3d3vfc4((7yd0dbrakhvi'
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode('PXItJGIqOGhnbG0rODU4Jjl0MDQzaGxtNi0mNi0zZDN2ZmM0KCg3eWQwZGJyYWtodmkxODAwNQ==')
'=r-$b*8hglm+858&9t043hlm6-&6-3d3vfc4((7yd0dbrakhvi18005'
>>> '=' + key + str(18005) == _
True
```

are you absolutely sure you used the same code on the server?

Comment: thanks for the explananation. Yes, I'm sure I used the same code. I tested my django code on the local machine first, then did 'manage.py deploy' without changing anything.

Comment: @Bahodir Did your code ever do something different? Because I think we can be fairly confident that this isn't Python deciding to do something different with your code on the server.

Comment: '=' is used as padding.  See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#base64Url()